# Missing something in import statement?

Tags: python

What exactly am I missing there? The path is: 
"projectname" -> django-project -> xyz_core- > management -> commands 
-> mail_handling.py

and my import statement says:

```
from xyz_core.management.commands import mail_handling
```

but it still gives me an error that it's unresolved and unused (unused definitely not true).

ErrorMessage:

Unused import statement
Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Unresolved reference 'management'
Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items

Solution:

```
from xyz_core.management.commands.mail_handling import *
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the django-project in front of it? Are there `__init__.py` files in every directory?

Comment: Please show the complete and exact error; not your own variant/interpretation of it.

Comment: @9769953 Yes sir, there is a __init__.py file in every directory. And putting django-project in front of it doesn't work either. It says invalid syntax because of the "-".

Comment: Is the name of your Django project exactly "django-project"?

Comment: ThisL "Unused import statement" is *not* an error message. It's a *warning* message from a linter, since you're probably not using `mail_handling` anywhere in your code. Just remove the whole import line, and the warning will be gone.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Solution is to append the .py file at the and of commands

```
from xyz_core.management.commands.mail_handling import *
```

Comment: Importing everything from a namespace is rarely a good idea, due to possible name collisions. I also don't expect this actually solves the issues, since it doesn't fundamentally change anything.